# Issue with multi-column In predicates are not supported in the DELETE condition

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, databricks-community-edition

I am using spark2.4.5 with java8 in my spark job which writes data into an s3 path.
Due to multiple triggers of job accidentally, it created duplicate records.
I am trying to remove the duplicates from s3 path using databricks.

While i am trying to perform delete operation as below from table "final_vals"

```
%sql
delete  from final_vals where rank1 in (select rank1 from ( select  ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by   id,data_date,data_type,data_value, version_id order by create_date,last_update_date ) as rank1
from final_vals )
 where rank1 <> 1 )  ;
```

Its throwing error as below

> Error in SQL statement: DeltaAnalysisException: Multi-column In predicates are not supported in the DELETE condition.

How to fix this issue? what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Kombajn zbożowy any clue what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: can you share sample data of your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your scenario and getting similar error
[image]

The error might be causing because of the Delete in databricks while using predicates some limitations are there like:

> The following types of subqueries are not supported:
>
> - **Nested subqueries, that is, an subquery inside another subquery**
> - `NOT IN`  subquery inside an  `OR`, for example,  `a = 3 OR b NOT IN (SELECT c from t)`

The work around is

Create dataframe with your query from which you are trying to get rank1  column

```py
df2 =  spark.sql("select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Variable_code,Variable_name order by Value ) as rank1 from exporttablemydemocsv") 
df2.show()
```

[image]

Then create another table with data frame and after that delete the rows where rank1 is not equal to 1 and delete that column.

```py
df2.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("exporttablemydemocsv3")

%sql
delete from exporttablemydemocsv3 where rank1!=1;

%sql
ALTER TABLE exporttablemydemocsv3 DROP COLUMN rank1
```

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: let me try this , but i need to update the same table/s3 path.